# How to define a function that counts the exponents

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

I want to define a function $F$ described as follows:

1. The input of $F$ is a polynomial such as

   ```
   m*u*x^4*y + n*v*x^2*y^3
   ```

   where $m$ and $n$ are constants, and $u$, $v$, $x$ and $y$ are variables.
2. Assume that $F$ receives a monomial.
   Then $F$ counts the number of exponents of $x$ and $y$ in the following way.

   ```
   F(x^k*y^l) = (k, k+l).
   ```

   More generally,

   ```
   F(m*u*x^k*y^l) = m*(k, k+l).
   ```

   Here the constant $m$ is multiplied in front of the 2-tuple,
   while we ignore the variable $u$ because we just want to count the exponents of $x$ and $y$ only. Hence it holds that for instance

   ```
   F(x^4) = (4,4)
   F(x^2y^3) = (2,5)
   ```

   and

   ```
   F(2xy^2) = 2(1,3).
   ```
3. Finally, suppose that $F$ receives a polynomial. In this case,

   ```
   F(mux^4*y + nvx^2*y^3) = m*(4,5) + n*(2,5).
   ```

   As a matter of fact, I prefer **not** to compute the result $m*(4,5) + n*(2,5)$ so that it becomes $(4m+2n, 5m+5n)$.

Could you help me in defining this function?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you please explain the logic of why *m* is used but *u* is discarded?

Comment: Also why *F(x^4)* should yield *(4,4)* rather than *(4,0)*.

Comment: The only characters $m$ and $n$ serve as constants. ($m$ and $n$ denote quantities like the dimension of the problem.) Except them, every character is regarded as a variable. In particular $u$, $v$, $x$ and $y$ are considered to be variables. I want to count the exponents of $x$ and $y$ only, discarding the other variables $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Also, I want to regard $x^4$ as $x^4y^0$. Since `F(x^ky^l) = (k, k+l)`, we should have $F(x^4) = F(x^4y^0) = (4, 4+0) = (4,4)$. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose

```
pol = m*u*x^4*y + n*v*x^2*y^3

Defer@*Times @@@ CoefficientRules[pol /. {u|v -> 1, x -> x y}, {x, y}] // Total
(* {4, 5} m + {2, 5} n *)
```

Use `Composition[Defer, Times]` instead of `Defer@*Times` if you have version 9 or earlier.

A more general definition:

```
vars = {x, y};
ignore = {u, v};

Defer@Times@## &[#2, Accumulate@#[[;; Length[vars]]]] & @@@ 
  CoefficientRules[pol, Join[vars, ignore]] // Total
(* n {2, 5} + m {4, 5} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to understand your suggestion.

Comment: The answer is what I really wanted. I sincerely appreciate for it!

Comment: This doesn't appear to yield the desired output for `x^k*y^l` or `m*u*x^k*y^l`, the first two examples.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, unfortunately, `CoefficientRules` works with integer powers only.

Comment: I guess that's not a problem for the OP since he Accepted it.  Vote restored.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I had to explain the condition more clearly. In my case, $k$ and $l$ are integers. Thank you for the message.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that I need to care negative integer powers as well. [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62967/coefficientrules-for-negative-powers)

Answer (score 4):

There is an internal function that might be of use here.

```
pol = m*u*x^4*y + n*v*x^2*y^3;
GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[pol, {u, v, x, y}][[1]]

(* Out[176]= {{{1, 0, 4, 1}, m}, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, n}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks :) It seems good for me. I will check it out.