# CoefficientRules for negative powers

Tags: functions, polynomials

`CoefficientRules` acts like the following.

```
In[1]:= CoefficientRules[2 x^3 + 3 x^2 y + 4 x y^2 - 5 x + 1]
Out[1]= {{3, 0} -> 2, {2, 1} -> 3, {1, 2} -> 4, {1, 0} -> -5, {0, 0} -> 1}
```

My question is how one can "extend" this function so that it may allow the negative integer power of the variable as its input.
In particular, I would like to obtain a `function` such that

```
In[2]:= function[2 x^3 + 3 x^(-2) y + 4 x y^2 - 5 y^(-3) + 1]
Out[2]= {{3, 0} -> 2, {-2, 1} -> 3, {1, 2} -> 4, {0, -3} -> -5, {0, 0} -> 1}
```

instead of getting

```
In[3]:= CoefficientRules[2 x^3 + 3 x^(-2) y + 4 x y^2 - 5 y^(-3) + 1]
Out[3]= {{0, 0} -> 1 + 2 x^3 - 5/y^3 + (3 y)/x^2 + 4 x y^2}
```

Could you answer for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my try that is something trick.

```
function[eq_] := CoefficientRules[eq /.
    Power[a_, b_?(# < 0 &)] -> Power[a, -10^10 b]] /.
  a_?(# > 10^9 &) -> -a/10^10

function[2 x^3 + 3 x^(-2) y + 4 x y^2 - 5 y^(-3) + 1]
```

> `{{-2, 1} -> 3, {3, 0} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 4, {0, -3} -> -5, {0, 0} -> 1}`

Comment: This trick is quite interesting and instructive for me. I sincerely thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

There is nice undocumented function

```
{c, v} = GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[2 x^3 + 3 x^(-2) y + 4 x y^2 - 5 y^(-3) + 1]
(* {{{{2, 0, 0, 1}, 3}, {{0, 3, 0, 0}, 2}, {{0, 1, 0, 2}, 
   4}, {{0, 0, 3, 0}, -5}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, 1}}, {1/x, x, 1/y, y}} *)
```

Then one can simplify the result

```
Transpose@{Transpose[c[[All, 1]].Replace[v, {# -> 1, 1/# -> -1, _ -> 0}, 1] & /@ 
    Variables[v]], c[[All, 2]]}
(* {{{-2, 1}, 3}, {{3, 0}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 4}, {{0, -3}, -5}, {{0, 0}, 1}} *)
```

Comment: `DistributedTermsList` is getting a lot of playing time today.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see how much one can do with Groebner bases. This a more elementary solution:

```
function[pol_] := Module[{vars, v, h, aux},
  vars = Variables[pol];
  v = Length[vars];
  h /: h[arg_]^p_ := h [p *arg];
  h /: h[arg1_] h[arg2_] := h[arg1 + arg2];
  (List @@ pol) /. 
    Table[vars[[n]] -> h[UnitVector[v, n]], {n, 1, v}] /.
       {c_. h[arg_] :> arg -> c, x_ /; NumericQ[x] && FreeQ[x, h] :> Table[0, {v}] -> x}
]

function[2 x^3 + 3 x^(-2) y + 4 x y^2 - 5 y^(-3) + 1]

(* {{0, 0} -> 1, {3, 0} -> 2, {0, -3} -> -5, {-2, 1} -> 3, {1, 2} -> 4} *)
```

Comment: `DistributedTermsList` lives in `GroebnerBasis` context but does not use GB in any way. It's actually a preprocessing function used by GB to put polynomials into a certain internal form.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for this remark. I did not look careful enough ...

Answer (score 0):

```
  fun[ex_] := Module[{v, p, m, mn, cp},
  v = Variables[ex];
  p = Cases[ex, Power[#, a_] :> a, Infinity] & /@ v;
  m = (Min /@ p);
  mn = (1 - Sign[#]) #/2 & /@ m;
  {If[Min[m] > 0, CoefficientRules[ex],
    cp = Times @@ MapThread[Power[#1, -#2] &, {v, mn}] ex;
    (#1 + mn -> #2) & @@@ CoefficientRules[Expand[cp], v]], v}
  ]
```

Testing:

```
exp = 2 x^3 + 3 x^(-2) y + 4 x y^2 - 5 y^(-3) + 1
```

then

```
fun[exp]
```

yields:

```
{{{3, 0} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 4, {0, 0} -> 1, {0, -3} -> -5, {-2, 1} -> 
   3}, {x, y}}
```

You can recover polynomial:

```
FromCoefficientRules@@fun[exp]
```

or if you wish to change variables:

```
FromCoefficientRules[First@fun[exp],{a,b}]
```

yielding: 1 + 2 a^3 - 5/b^3 + (3 b)/a^2 + 4 a b^2

Or

```
fun[3 + a^2 b^-3 + c^-3 d^3 + a^-2 b^2 d^3]
```

yields:

```
{{{2, -3, 0, 0} -> 1, {0, 0, 3, -3} -> 1, {0, 0, 0, 0} -> 
   3, {-2, 2, 3, 0} -> 1}, {a, b, d, c}}
```